# multi count with diff condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `event_tbl`with columns `id,add_date,name,events`;
and I want count all rows and the latest add_date count, how can I get that in one sql statement?

```
select count(1) as total
from event_tbl
union
select count(id) as latestCount from event_tbl where add_date=(select max(add_date) 
from event_tbl);
```

but the result is :

```
------
total|
------
 5499|
-----
 611 |
```

what is correct way with efficiency?

Comment: Really quick, what is wrong with the current result? Do you want result in two columns instead of rows?

Comment: @Parfait yes, I want the result in two columns casue I want name the second columns as `latestCount`, also I think the efficiency is important because the table has many rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
select count(*) as total, sum(add_date = maxad) as lastestCount
from event_tbl e cross join
     (select max(add_date) as maxad from event_tbl) ee;
```

Comment: thanks for answer so quick, would you please explain the efficiency compare to the two separate sql statements?

Comment: @WesleyHsiung . .  You would need to test on your data and your system.  I suspect that the performance would be similar in MySQL.